# Change column type from bigint to numeric(18,0) in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, alter

I have around 10 tables which have data in them. I need to change the fields which have data type **bigint** to **numeric(18,0).**

We have verified data in our DB, there would not be any data loss. In our lower environment, what we have done is:

1. Took backup for existing table, renamed it temporarily
2. Create a new table with numeric data type
3. Populate data from backup table
4. If everything is okay, then delete backup table

The above is the process we have followed in **lower** environments.

But, we cannot follow above procedure when it comes to prod. We would like to change using ALTER statement. Since it is PROD environment, we have to be careful with changes. As I said earlier, there would not be any data loss.

But still wanted to know - what internally happens when we execute the `ALTER` statement?

**Will it drop the table and recreate it with new definitions and populate the data back?** If so, are there any risk associated with this?

Any thoughts on how this could be properly handled in PROD would be appreciated.

Comment: But why go from bigint to numeric(18,0)? I'd do the opposite...

Comment: I am working on mapping this with MS Access linked tables. Bigint will convert as text in Access not as numeric where as numeric in SQL sever will be correctly mapped as numeric

Comment: If you alter table using query then internally it'll not drop and recreate the table. Don't do it using SSMS.

Comment: The only risk is the temporary outage that this will cause... What other risks do you have in mind? SQL Server does not allow corruption to happen.

Comment: @usr..can you please elaborate on above . will sql server internally drops and creates a new table ?

Comment: You don't need the answer to that question. You need to test this in a staging environment and measure how long it takes and how much tlog it takes. Regardless of the answer to your question.

Comment: okay..temporary outage is not a problem , because we have a  good enough window of ime alloacted for the release

Comment: What is your question, then? What are your concerns?

Comment: @usr..my question is whether it is proper approach to do it in PROD

Answer (score 1):

I might suggest an approach that doesn't rebuild the data.  Use a computed column instead.  Something like this:

```
sp_rename 'table.dbo.col', '_col', 'COLUMN';

alter table table add col as (cast(_col as numeric(18, 0));
```

You can then access `col` as the type that you want.  You will not have to rewrite any data, so there will not be any locks or other issues with performance.  Of course, `select *` will be a bit redundant, but you probably shouldn't be doing that anyway.

Comment: I'd jsut go for the added computed column, not renaming the columns otherwise you are going to affect all existing reads, inserts and updates